# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty (I've searched all answers already)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails.

For some reason this won't work and I'm frustrated trying things. This is for a jobs board project.

Jobs Controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end   

  def create
    Job.create(job_params)
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end   

  private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description)
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end   


end
```

Partial form:

```html
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, size: '60x6' %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

edit job:

```html
<h1>Edit job posting</h1>

<%= render "form" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the edit action below `private` move it above. Controller actions are not accessible by none other that the object itself, if they are private. Move the update action above private also. if you want it to update your @job

    `def update
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
      @job.update(job_params)
      redirect_to jobs_path
    end`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `Job.find(params[:id])` returns instance of `Job`? Maybe none Job is found for your `params[:id]`, and that is why you have nil.

Comment: How can I verify this? The form works fine to add a new job but the edit page is the one that breaks and they are using the same form. I'm not sure if they are connected.

Thanks for your response